# enviar data json desde controlador a un componente vuejs y mostrarlo

Tags: laravel, vue.js, component

hola estoy realizando un update  un registro, la cuestión es cuando este update se realiza mando el resultado a un componente vuejs, y lo envía, el problema es que esa data luego tengo que mostrarlo en otro componente, pero no se como puedo capturar los datos desde el componente al cual lo estoy enviando, esto es lo que tengo, mi template, la vista en la cual pretendo mostrar lo que retorno desde un controllador:

```js
<template>
<!-- /.contenedor principal -->
    <div class="container "   >
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" >

                        <!-- Main content -->
                        <div class="invoice p-3 mb-3">
                         
                          <div class="row invoice-info" >
                            <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
                              
                              <address >
                                <strong>  {{}}</strong><br>
                                <strong>  {{}}</strong><br>
                               </address>
                            </div>
         
                          </div>

                        </div>
 
                      </div>
        </div>   
    </div>

</template>
<!-- /.comienzo del script -->
<script>

    export default {
         mounted() {
            
           
            
        },


         data(){
             return{  
             pedidos:{},

            }
        },

        methods:{
              
              printme() {
          window.print();
      }
        },
        created(){
      
         
    }
    }
</script>
```

luego tengo mi controlador:

```js
public function update(Request $request, $codigo)
    {  
        $pedido = Pedido::findOrFail($codigo);
        $pedido->estado_pedidos = 2;
        $pedido->fecha_venta = Carbon::now();
        $pedido->numero_venta = $request->get('numero_venta');
        $pedido->valor = $request->get('valor');
        
        $pedido->save();

        return json_encode (array(view('Home'), 'pedido' => $pedido));
        
    }
```

bueno, acá me encuentro con el problema de que estoy mandando la vista con el array, como podria enviarlo a un componente vue, y cargar la  data en el componente ? seria de mucha ayuda ya que llevo 2 dias tratando de solucionarlo gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Los componentes tienen diferentes tipos de comunicaciones dependiendo de cómo deseas compartir información. Un componente padre se puede comunicar y transferir información a un componente hijo gracias a las `props`. [La documentación](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) da un ejemplo claro al respecto:

```javascript
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['postTitle'],
  template: '<h3>{{ postTitle }}</h3>'
})
```

```html
<blog-post post-title="hello!"></blog-post>
```

Si lo que deseas es enviar información desde un componente hijo a un padre, entonces deberías utilizar [la emisión de eventos](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event).

```javascript
methods: {
  onEnlargeText: function (enlargeAmount) {
    this.postFontSize += enlargeAmount
  }
}
```

```html
<button @enlarge-text="onEnlargeText">
  Enlarge text
</button>
```